# changing the forecolor at runtime of label which is present in template field of gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am creating one application using gridview of asp.net. Grid view containing one template which having 3 to 4 labels which bind from database values.One label of gridview tamplate forecolor is blue but after selecting row i want to change color to white to selected row label to white but my problem is all other label colors is changed but that blue color label color is remaining.
I am using following code to change color of all labels At gridview selectedindex changed event.
For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            If i = GridView1.SelectedIndex Then

```
     GridView1.SelectedRow.Attributes.Add("style", "background-image: url('images/weight-loss-li-over.gif'); color : white;")
        Else
            GridView1.Rows(i).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
            GridView1.Rows(i).Font.Bold = False
            GridView1.Rows(i).Attributes.Remove("style")

        End If
    Next
```

pls give me any answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your code as follwos, i think it will help you.

```
      For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim txt As Label = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).FindControl("lblProgram"), Label)
            If i = GridView1.SelectedIndex Then
                txt.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.White
                GridView1.SelectedRow.Attributes.Add("style", "background-image: url('images/weight-loss-li-over.gif'); color: white;")
            Else
                GridView1.Rows(i).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
                txt.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Blue
                GridView1.Rows(i).Attributes.Remove("style")
            End If
        Next
```

If it not resolve your problem then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't try CSS or JavaScript approches?
CSS hover: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp
JavaScript onClick: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: but how to use css at run time after selecting gridview row

Comment: Maysam if i click on grid view that time my whole template is select and that time other label colors are changed white but blue fore olor label not changed pls give any ans.

Comment: i am not using any <a></a> link in my grid view

Comment: blue color labels are hyper links?

Comment: sorry for late give you answer for your quetion

Comment: that label only a simple label

Comment: post HTML output of DataGridView

Comment: can you tell me how can change under the templatefield control forecolor at runtime

Comment: where is screenshot of output? i'm thinking to a javascript solution.

Comment: where can i attach screen shot here any facility to atach screen shot i am developing asp.net application

Comment: I mean how can i attach screen shot

Comment: upload to a image hosting website then post image URL here.